# How can I create a dummy matrix from two lists with common values?

Tags: r, tidyr, reshape2, model.matrix

In R, I have multiple very large (on the order of 140e6) lists of IP addresses.  There are many overlap IPs between the multiple lists.  I'd like to create a data frame or data table that contains the ip address as the rowname (without duplicates) and the list names as the columns and a 0 or 1 that indicates whether the ip exists in that list.

For example, we have the following two lists, with some % intersection between the two.

```
a <- c("192.168.0.1","192.168.0.2","192.168.0.3","192.168.0.4","192.168.0.5","192.168.0.6","192.168.0.7","192.168.0.8","192.168.0.9","192.168.0.10")
b <- c("192.168.1.1","192.168.1.2","192.168.1.3","192.168.1.4","192.168.0.5","192.168.0.6","192.168.0.7","192.168.0.8","192.168.0.9","192.168.0.10")
```

What I would like is this:

```
             a b
192.168.0.1  1 0
192.168.0.2  1 0
192.168.0.3  1 0
192.168.0.4  1 0
192.168.0.5  1 1
192.168.0.6  1 1
192.168.0.7  1 1
192.168.0.8  1 1
192.168.0.9  1 1
192.168.0.10 1 1
192.168.1.1  0 1
192.168.1.2  0 1
192.168.1.3  0 1
192.168.1.4  0 1
```

I have tried using reshape2, tidyr, model.matrix, intersect and good ol' for loops.  I've found a few examples of people creating dummy matrices from data frames, but not with the vector name as the column and the value as the rowname, and not with duplicates.

Answer (score 2):

**First I'll introduce 2 new solutions**

A solution with merge

```
df1 <- merge(data.frame(ip=a,a=1), data.frame(ip=b,b=1),all=TRUE) %>%
set_rownames(.,`[`(.,,'ip')) %>% select(-ip) %>% replace(.,is.na(.),0)

#              a b
# 192.168.0.1  1 0
# 192.168.0.10 1 1
# 192.168.0.2  1 0
# 192.168.0.3  1 0
# 192.168.0.4  1 0
# 192.168.0.5  1 1
# 192.168.0.6  1 1
# 192.168.0.7  1 1
# 192.168.0.8  1 1
# 192.168.0.9  1 1
# 192.168.1.1  0 1
# 192.168.1.2  0 1
# 192.168.1.3  0 1
# 192.168.1.4  0 1
```

---

And here's also a solution with reshape

The cool thing about this one is that it works when you have more than 2 source vectors:

```
df2 <- list(data.frame(a),data.frame(b)) %>%
  lapply(. %>% transform(source = names(.)) %>% rename_("ip" = names(.)[1])) %>%
  do.call(rbind,.) %>%
  transform(v=1) %>%
  reshape(idvar="ip",timevar="source",direction="wide",sep="") %>%
  replace(.,is.na(.),0) %>%
  setNames(gsub("v","",colnames(.))) %>%
  set_rownames(.,`[`(.,,'ip')) %>% select(-ip)

#              a b
# 192.168.0.1  1 0
# 192.168.0.2  1 0
# 192.168.0.3  1 0
# 192.168.0.4  1 0
# 192.168.0.5  1 1
# 192.168.0.6  1 1
# 192.168.0.7  1 1
# 192.168.0.8  1 1
# 192.168.0.9  1 1
# 192.168.0.10 1 1
# 192.168.1.1  0 1
# 192.168.1.2  0 1
# 192.168.1.3  0 1
# 192.168.1.4  0 1
```

---

**Benchmark of all solutions for 2 vectors**

let's benchmark the solutions offered so far. I add in a variation of my first solution using `data.table` and variations of my second solution using `dcast` from `reshape2` and `spread` from `tidyR`

```
microbenchmark(
merge = merge(data.frame(ip=a,a=1), data.frame(ip=b,b=1),all=TRUE) %>%
  set_rownames(.,`[`(.,,'ip')) %>% select(-ip) %>% replace(.,is.na(.),0),
merge_dt = merge(data.table(ip=a,a=1,key="ip"), data.table(ip=b,b=1,key="ip"),all=TRUE) %>%
  as.data.frame %>% # to go back to desired output format
  set_rownames(.,`[`(.,,'ip')) %>% select(-ip) %>% replace(.,is.na(.),0),
dcast = list(data.frame(a),data.frame(b)) %>%
  lapply(. %>% transform(source = names(.)) %>% rename_("ip" = names(.)[1])) %>%
  do.call(rbind,.) %>%
  transform(v=1) %>%
  dcast(ip ~ source,value.var="v") %>%
  replace(.,is.na(.),0) %>%
  setNames(gsub("v","",colnames(.))) %>%
  set_rownames(.,`[`(.,,'ip')) %>% select(-ip),
spread = list(data.frame(a),data.frame(b)) %>%
  lapply(. %>% transform(source = names(.)) %>% rename_("ip" = names(.)[1])) %>%
  do.call(rbind,.) %>%
  transform(v=1) %>%
  spread(source,v) %>%
  replace(.,is.na(.),0) %>%
  setNames(gsub("v","",colnames(.))) %>%
  set_rownames(.,`[`(.,,'ip')) %>% select(-ip),
reshape = list(data.frame(a),data.frame(b)) %>%
  lapply(. %>% transform(source = names(.)) %>% rename_("ip" = names(.)[1])) %>%
  do.call(rbind,.) %>%
  transform(v=1) %>%
  reshape(idvar="ip",timevar="source",direction="wide",sep="") %>%
  replace(.,is.na(.),0) %>%
  setNames(gsub("v","",colnames(.))) %>%
  set_rownames(.,`[`(.,,'ip')) %>% select(-ip),
akrun   = {lvl <- unique(c(a,b));mapply(table, list(a = factor(a, levels = lvl),b = factor(b, levels = lvl)))},
p_routh = {df <- data.frame("IP" = unique(c(a,b)));df2 <- df%>%mutate(a = ifelse(df$IP %in% a,1,0),b = ifelse(df$IP %in% b,1,0))},
d.b     = {ALL  <- unique(c(a,b));data.frame(sapply(list(a = a, b = b), function(x) as.numeric(ALL %in% x)), row.names = ALL)},
times = 100
)
```

For the given example :

```
# Unit: microseconds
#     expr      min        lq      mean    median        uq       max neval
#    merge 2368.754 2670.8205 3866.2288 2942.6280 3685.1415 38459.947   100
# merge_dt 4220.084 4702.4700 5547.1978 5222.3705 6239.1685  9170.293   100
#    dcast 6153.875 6870.3760 9031.8770 7521.7570 8793.9045 46529.917   100
#   spread 4329.090 4814.6610 6023.5993 5313.3275 6301.9890 38972.416   100
#  reshape 4376.514 5007.1905 5995.1480 5694.1395 6811.4495  8744.180   100
#    akrun  238.893  304.3680  366.0376  327.7265  416.3815   654.744   100
#  p_routh 1013.967 1190.9255 1418.8037 1296.7450 1651.7220  2162.775   100
#      d.b  133.072  183.8595  228.7220  207.0415  278.1780   417.974   100
```

For a bigger example :
140E6 is a bit much to benchmark so I try with 1E5. I arbitrarily choose an overlap of about 50% between a and b.

```
n <- 1E5
set.seed(1)
a <- sample(2*n,n)
b <- sample(2*n,n)
```

and I run the benchmark 10 times

```
# Unit: milliseconds
#     expr       min       lq      mean    median       uq      max neval
#    merge 582.41885 617.4348 676.40615 651.84618 698.1091 911.8320    10
# merge_dt  98.72318 100.6648 114.72754 103.57925 119.9722 176.5360    10
#    dcast 267.51729 347.8337 366.85554 360.17472 411.5002 454.1912    10
#   spread 425.26005 447.7959 471.03577 477.02525 490.0484 502.8333    10
#  reshape 697.14005 738.6921 763.31876 751.01547 791.3207 818.0778    10
#    akrun 791.00964 815.5621 838.08296 832.31382 849.5231 923.6849    10
#  p_routh  78.77724  82.8646  98.38296  84.34238 101.7304 151.0339    10
#      d.b 191.00546 194.5754 209.02133 200.35484 207.1666 279.7900    10
```

We see that P Routh's solution is the fastest for 2 vectors and `dcast` is the fastest general solution. `merge` with `data.table` might be the fastest for 140E6 rows however.

---

**General solutions**

Hopefulle final edit:

I designed 2 general solutions based on my best restricted ones, and ran them on 3 vectors of size 10E6.

```
merge_dt_gen <- function(...){
  args <- as.character(substitute(list(...)))[-1]
  dts <- args %>% lapply(.%>% data.table(ip=get(.),key="ip"))
  all_ips <- data.table(ip = unique(c(...)),key="ip") # all_ips <- data.table(ip = unique(c(a,b)))
  for(dt in dts){
    all_ips <- merge(all_ips,dt,all.x = TRUE,by="ip")
  }
  all_ips %>%
    as.data.frame %>%
    set_rownames(.,`[`(.,,'ip')) %>%
    select(-ip) %>%
    setNames(args) %>%
    replace(.,!is.na(.),1) %>%
    replace(.,is.na(.),0) 
}

d_cast_gen <- function(...){
  args <- as.character(substitute(list(...)))[-1]
  args %>%
    lapply(.%>% data.frame(get(.)) %>% setNames(c("src","ip"))) %>% 
    do.call(rbind,.) %>%
    transform(v=1) %>%
    dcast(ip ~ src,value.var="v") %>%
    replace(.,is.na(.),0) %>%
    setNames(gsub("v","",colnames(.))) %>%
    set_rownames(.,`[`(.,,'ip')) %>% select(-ip)  
}

n <- 10E6
set.seed(1)
a <- sample(2*n,n)
b <- sample(2*n,n)
d <- sample(unique(a,b),n)

microbenchmark(
  d_cast_gen   = d_cast_gen(a,b,d),
  merge_dt_gen = merge_dt_gen(a,b,d),
  times = 1
)

# Unit: seconds
#         expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
#   d_cast_gen 70.99771 70.99771 70.99771 70.99771 70.99771 70.99771     1
# merge_dt_gen 47.41809 47.41809 47.41809 47.41809 47.41809 47.41809     1
```

`merge` with `data.table` is the fastest

Answer (score 0):

A dplyr solution:

```
df <- data.frame("IP" = unique(c(a,b)))
df2 <- df%>%mutate(a = ifelse(df$IP %in% a,1,0),b = ifelse(df$IP %in% b,1,0))
```

Output:

```
> df2
             IP a b
1   192.168.0.1 1 0
2   192.168.0.2 1 0
3   192.168.0.3 1 0
4   192.168.0.4 1 0
5   192.168.0.5 1 1
6   192.168.0.6 1 1
7   192.168.0.7 1 1
8   192.168.0.8 1 1
9   192.168.0.9 1 1
10 192.168.0.10 1 1
11  192.168.1.1 0 1
12  192.168.1.2 0 1
13  192.168.1.3 0 1
14  192.168.1.4 0 1
```

Answer (score 0):

We can do this with by converting 'a', 'b', to `factor` with `levels` specified as `unique` elements in combined 'a', 'b' and get the frequency

```
lvl <- unique(c(a,b))
mapply(table, list(a = factor(a, levels = lvl),b = factor(b, levels = lvl)))
#             a b
#192.168.0.1  1 0
#192.168.0.2  1 0
#192.168.0.3  1 0
#192.168.0.4  1 0
#192.168.0.5  1 1
#192.168.0.6  1 1
#192.168.0.7  1 1
#192.168.0.8  1 1
#192.168.0.9  1 1
#192.168.0.10 1 1
#192.168.1.1  0 1
#192.168.1.2  0 1
#192.168.1.3  0 1
#192.168.1.4  0 1
```

Comment: Not sure why, but i got different results with this one than with the others:
    [1] "dplyr a matches are :  11999"
    [1] "dplyr b matches are :  6179"
    [1] "sapply a matches are :  11999"  
    [1] "sapply b matches are :  6179"
    [1] "mapply a matches are :  10998"
    [1] "mapply b matches are :  3001"

Comment: @TheProletariat  Not sure about that.  Do you have `NA` values

Comment: There shouldn't be any NAs in there.  I will look into it and see if I can figure out why it's different.  Nope:  > length(mapply_df[is.na(mapply_df)])
[1] 0  I'll keep looking.